# MPDF - Error when displaying currency symbols from database

Tags: mpdf

I have a table in mysql that stores currency symbols like € and £ . I get the following error while displaying the symbol from database in a mpdf document - HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s).
When these symbols are hardcoded in php,mpdf does not throw any error.The currency symbol column  has utf8_general_ci collation.

Thanks ,
Simmy

Answer (score 1):

I did this for alternate chars:

```
<?php
include('class/mpdf.php');

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252';
```